# Paging and sorting using Open Api 3.0 in Spring boot project?

Tags: spring-boot, sorting, pagination, springdoc-openapi-ui, openapi-3-0

Im very new to Spring boot. I'm doing a project in Spring boot 3.2.5 with Maven. I have used Springdoc Open Api 3.0 in the project. I have implemented paging and sorting. Could you help me customize the default size and sorting criteria in the same? Do I need to configure?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, and it was pretty easy. You just need to add **@PageableDefault** as shown below. You may even change the default page number using 'page = "value" '.

```java
public Entity findAll(@ParameterObject @PageableDefault(size = 5, sort = "name")Pageable pageable)
```